# Mule 4/DW2.0 - Convert ["B_B001","C_C001", "D_D01" ] to ('B_B001','C_C001', 'D_D01' )

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Input -
["B_B001","C_C001", "D_D01" ]

Output -
('B_B001','C_C001', 'D_D01' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. Assuming this is a payload in an array and you want to change it to an output shown on your example as a text/plain, try the following script:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
"('" ++ (payload joinBy "','") ++ "')"
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of data on how you need to approach the solution. Here you have a solution for two input types: JSON and String. Both return a String with the desired format.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var asJson = ["B_B001","C_C001", "D_D01" ]
var asString = '["B_B001","C_C001", "D_D01" ]'
---
{
    fromJson: "('" ++ (asJson joinBy("','")) ++ "')",
    fromString: (( asString replace "[" with "(") replace  "]" with ")") replace  "\"" with "'"
}
```

Output

```
{   
  "fromJson": "('B_B001','C_C001','D_D01')",   
  "fromString": "('B_B001','C_C001', 'D_D01' )" 
}
```